# ASP.NET AJAX ToolkitScriptManager Issue With Combining Scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 web application in which i am using the ToolkitScriptManager as below:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" ScriptMode="Release"
    LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" runat="server" CombineScripts="false">
 <CompositeScript>
<Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/Validators.js" />
</Scripts>
 </CompositeScript>
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

This works fine but from a performance standpoint this is not good as the pages are making a lot of requests to the webresources.axd and scriptresource.axd files. When I changed the CombineScripts property to true my ASP.NET AJAX control extenders are no longer working. What is the reason for this weired behavior and is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

In order to enable an actual script combination, you have to implement a IHttpHandler and reference it into the CombineScriptsHandlerUrl 's porperty of your ToolkitScriptManager.

You have a full example in the sample application delivered with the lastest version of the ControlToolkit ;-)

Oinant